# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError exception

Tags: java, ant

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:63)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.<clinit>(Project.java:131)
            at Pv.plugin_execute(Pv.java:140)
            at Pv.main(Pv.java:194)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os.<clinit>(Os.java:31)
            ... 4 more
```

This is my code to run an ant target from my java file.
 I have set all the parameters for it.
 Code runs on Linux environment.

```
File buildFile = new File(bDir + "/" + pBDir + "/"+ atBFile);
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
p.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(p, buildFile);
p.executeTarget(target);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Yesterday it was running fine, today it gave me this exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given [the source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/condition/Os.java?view=markup) it looks like you don't have the system property of "os.name" set for some reason. You should look into *why* that's not set, but you could always specify it manually from the command line if necessary.

Comment: When i do    System.out.println("os.name="+System.getProperty("os.name"));            I get Linux as the property value. so that is not the reason

Comment: @user1731553: Are you running that code in *exactly* the same way as you are in the code that invokes Ant? (You might also want to check the other properties shown in that file.)

Comment: the error comes for line: Project p = new Project();                Also: the command I am using to run it is:                          java -Xmx256m -cp '.:/sc/su/repo/pro/ant/lib/*:/sc/su/repo/pro/lib/*' Pv

Comment: @user1731553: So did you try printing out the os.name property on this line before that?

Comment: Thanks! so much....I got it now....did not knew that System.setPropery() appends to the existing list of property. where as System.setProperties() removes and creates a new list. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that since I was using System.setProperties() it removed the existing list of properties and created a new one.
however System.property() apends the property to the existing list.